# Downloading table from web from multiple pages

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to download table from multiple links via web.

```
Sub test()
    cnt = 0

    For i = 2 To 5
        temp = Cells(i, 1)

        lnk = Right(temp, Len(temp) - WorksheetFunction.Find("?", temp))
        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0", Formula:= _
            "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?"" & lnk))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""CALLS Chart"", type text}, {""CALLS OI"", type text}, {""CALLS Chng in OI"", type text}, {""CALLS Volume"", t" & _
            "ype text}, {""CALLS IV"", type text}, {""CALLS LTP"", type text}, {""CALLS Net Chng"", type text}, {""CALLS Bid Qty"", type text}, {""CALLS Bid Price"", type text}, {""CALLS Ask Price"", type text}, {""CALLS Ask Qty"", type text}, {""Strike Price"", type number}, {""PUTS Bid Qty"", type text}, {""PUTS Bid Price"", type text}, {""PUTS Ask Price"", type text}, {""PUTS" & _
            " Ask Qty"", type text}, {""PUTS Net Chng"", type text}, {""PUTS LTP"", type text}, {""PUTS IV"", type text}, {""PUTS Volume"", type text}, {""PUTS Chng in OI"", type text}, {""PUTS OI"", type text}, {""PUTS Chart"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
            "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0"";Extended Properties=""""" _
            , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
            .CommandType = xlCmdSql
            .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0]")
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
            .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table" & cnt
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Table 0").Delete
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

I get
[image]

As I got this code by recording a macro I'm stuck here in making the web page link dynamic.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=BAJAJ-AUTO&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{""CALLS Chart"", type text}, {""CALLS OI"", type text}, {""CALLS Chng in OI"", type text}, {""CALLS Volume"", t" & _
        "ype text}, {""CALLS IV"", type text}, {""CALLS LTP"", type text}, {""CALLS Net Chng"", type text}, {""CALLS Bid Qty"", type text}, {""CALLS Bid Price"", type text}, {""CALLS Ask Price"", type text}, {""CALLS Ask Qty"", type text}, {""Strike Price"", type number}, {""PUTS Bid Qty"", type text}, {""PUTS Bid Price"", type text}, {""PUTS Ask Price"", type text}, {""PUTS" & _
        " Ask Qty"", type text}, {""PUTS Net Chng"", type text}, {""PUTS LTP"", type text}, {""PUTS IV"", type text}, {""PUTS Volume"", type text}, {""PUTS Chng in OI"", type text}, {""PUTS OI"", type text}, {""PUTS Chart"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
```

Links for your reference:

1. https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=BAJAJ-AUTO&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17
2. https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=BAJAJFINSV&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17
3. https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=BAJFINANCE&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17

Comment: What's your desired behaviour? Do you want to create multiple tables, or overwrite/replace the existing `Table 0`?

Comment: I want to create new sheets for each table from web page..
Ref: Link 1: https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=BAJAJFINSV&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17
Ref:Link2: https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=BAJAJ-AUTO&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17

Comment: I have 100+ pages for downloading the tables!! Thank you for spending your time :)

Comment: After downloading i don't need the query Table 0. Hence, i'm deleting here ActiveWorkbook.Queries("Table 0").Delete

Comment: @jsheeran updated the error snap please check..

Comment: Are you downloading over 100 links?

Comment: Yes from 100 pages 100 tables..

Comment: @QHarr pattern will be the same please check the ref. links above. If possible kindly guide me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider XMLHTTP requests as a fast method to retrieve. I assume links are in column A of a sheet called `Links`, starting from row 1.

You would adjust your range

```
Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A3").Value)
```

to ensure you have all your links included.

I use the `symbol` to determine the sheet to write to. I use a slighty modified function by @Rory to test if sheet already exists, if not I create it. This assumes symbol doesn't repeat across URLs, otherwise you need to choose something unique for sheet naming.

I target the table by its id using a css id selector of `#octable`.

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub Test()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument, links(), hTable As HTMLTable
    Dim symbol As String, i As Long, ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Links")
    links = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A3").Value)

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(links) To UBound(links)
            If InStr(links(i), "http") > 0 Then
                .Open "GET", links(i), False
                .send
                sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)

                Set html = New HTMLDocument
                With html
                    .body.innerHTML = sResponse
                    Set hTable = .querySelector("#octable")
                End With
                symbol = Split(Split(links(i), "symbol=")(1), "&")(0)
                If Not WorksheetExists(symbol) Then
                    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                    wsTemp.NAME = symbol
                Else
                    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(symbol)
                End If
                If Not hTable Is Nothing Then
                    wsTemp.UsedRange.ClearContents
                    wsTemp.Cells(1, 1) = "CALLS": wsTemp.Cells(1, 13) = "PUTS"
                    WriteTable hTable, 2, wsTemp
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, C As Long, tBody As Object
    r = startRow
    With ws
        Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
        Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
        For Each header In headers
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            If columnCounter > 3 Then
            .Cells(startRow, columnCounter - 3) = header.innerText
            End If
        Next header
        startRow = startRow + 1
        Set tBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each tSection In tBody               'HTMLTableSection
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'HTMLTableRow
            For Each tr In tRow
                r = r + 1
                Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                C = 1
                For Each td In tCell             'DispHTMLElementCollection
                    .Cells(r, C).Value = td.innerText 'HTMLTableCell
                    C = C + 1
                Next td
            Next tr
        Next tSection
    End With
End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal sName As String) As Boolean  '<== @Rory
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much :)

Comment: I'm getting run time error '- 2146697211 800c0005 )': the system cannot locate the resource specified. could you please tell me why?

Comment: Does it only happen during long runs? Does it contunue to work over a few links?

Comment: Yes it is.. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Which URL does it fail on please?

Comment: https://www.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=CANBK&instrument=OPTSTK&date=-&segmentLink=17

Comment: I will have a look but it won't be until later.

Comment: That's absolutely fine.. Thanks!